video download crash after update sdk34
I have issue encountered in our application after updating to SDK 34.
I have noticed that users are unable to download videos from the app following this update.
It seems that there is a problem with the video downloading process, as the operation hangs and no content is downloaded.

View download = view.findViewById(R.id.download);
if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.downloads_enabled)) {
    download.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            submitForDownload();
        } else {
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    getString(R.string.permission_rationale_download),
                    SharedConstants.REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS_DOWNLOAD,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        }
    });
    download.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    download.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}


Your code doesn't include actual code for downloading anything. Apart from issues with permissions, we can only guess what is happening. Please provide more code, preferably a minimal example focused on your issue, and including any effort you took to debug it may be helpful too.

You probably do not need to request that permission at all, unless you trying to store the file somewhere outside your app's file storage area. The likely reason your app stalls at this point is that it is an invalid permission being passed when you requestPermission. You should check to see if the device is below API 29 before checking for the permission at all.
As mentioned elsewhere, you are using a deprecated permission to access files.
Both READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE were deprecated in API 32/29 respectively.
Android does provide a work-around that may help you if you do need this permission:
<manifest ... >
    <!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting Android 10 or above. -->
    <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-scoped-storage

There is a) no stack-trace of the crash (however, I can well imagine what it might complain about) and b) Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE does not exist in API 34 ...you'll have to migrate to modern API: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="29"/>

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="32"/>

maxSdkVersion="29" means that this stopped working years ago, not only with your recent update.
